# db2 cant stop getting transaction log is fill error

Tags: sql, db2

I am having a serious issue.. I have store procedure which updates, couple of million records. It all happens in a cursor.
I am having issues that whatever I have done so far, it fails with transaction log full error
SQL0964C The transaction log for the database is full. SQLSTATE=57011

Over the past couple of days I have, one by one, made following changes to db configuration in hopes that log file will STOP getting filled
I have set the following

```
LOGRETAIN = NO
LOGARCHMETH1 = OFF
LOGILESIZE=20000
LOGPRIMARY=50
LOGSECONDARY=200
```

Up to this morning ( Just changed LOGARCHMETH1 = OFF and sp is running) I have no luck. For now I just don't want to see this darn error, I wish this to stop so that I can move forward with my testing. I can deal with these performance issues later.
Can some kind soul shed some light how in the heck I force db2 to NOT use logs other than what I have already tried?
DB2 version is 8.2.4

Comment: There should be a problem in your update. Try to update partially (where condition)

Comment: I wonder if there is any thing wrong with update statement, as it has been running on ms sql server
here is the query
UPDATE table_name SET col2=@nextColId WHERE col1=@col1 AND col3 = @col3 AND col4=@col4;
there is a commit after the above statement which commits after every 500 recs

Comment: by the way question is why with all the settings I have, transaction log is still being written?

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the answer, Since I am not well versed with DB2 syntax, apparently the way I was using cursor was causing an "infinite loop"(?)
Anyways I changed my code to follow this format

```
FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT firstnme, midinit, lastname FROM employee
DO 
  SET fullname = v.lastname || ',' || v.firstnme 
                 ||' ' || v.midinit;
  INSERT INTO tnames VALUES (fullname);
END FOR;
```

and all worked perfectly..:-)

Hope it will help some other newbie like me with db2 syntax

Comment: I don't know if that is going to help anyone, as this is a very inefficient way of inserting "_a couple of million records_". One might consider using the LOAD from a cursor, which will indeed minimize logging.